# All UNexisting files and folders redirecting except for those with php extension

Tags: nginx, php, configuration

I use the following directive for my application:

```
location / {
    root  "C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-www";
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?param=$uri;
}
```

Which redirects all the unexisting files and folders to index.php with $_GET parameter of url, except for the php files where i get the following error:

> No input file specified.

Is there a workaround to make this work with the .php extension?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block

Comment: Please add your .php processing location to your question.